# PDFPage.attributedString returns the wrong font

Tags: ios, pdf

I'm reading an existing PDF using PDFKit. I get an attributedString for a page, but the fonts in the string don't match the fonts actually in the PDF:

The fonts in the PDF (according to several different apps) are:

```
CourierFinalDraft        (TypeType Roman) Embedded Subset
CourierFinalDraft-Bold   (TrueType Roman) Embedded Subset
CourierFinalDraft-Italic (TrueType Roman) Embedded Subset
```

My Swift code to get the font is:

```
guard let page = pdf.page(at: pageNo) else { return }
guard let content = page.attributedString else { return }
content.enumerateAttributes(in: range, options:[]) {(dict: [String:Any], range: NSRange, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
    let font = dict[NSFontAttributeName] as! UIFont
    }
```

All of the text is returned in a single range. The font returned has the following:

```
font-family: "Times New Roman"
font-name: "TimesNewRomanPSMT"
```

So the Bold and Italic text are returned in the same range as the normal text, and I can't distinguish among them, which is what I'm trying to do. As well as the font name I also look at:

```
font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitItalic)
```

but of course this is always False as all text is returned in the same range as if it is normal.

This is using the XCode simulator, in case that's relevant. The PDF does render correctly (including bold and italics) on Safari in the Simulator. Unfortunately I can't try it out on a real iPhone.

Comment: What's your question, exactly?

Comment: How can I get the correct font name from the attributedString or anywhere else. Alternatively, how I can find out which text on the page is italic or bold.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a few years old, but I found that I had to make a mutable copy of the data in order to interact with it and then use the information available to modify the underlying font and re-display it.

```
    let str = content.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
    str.beginEditing()
    str.enumerateAttribute(.font,
                           in: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.length),
                           options: []) { value, range, _ in
      guard let value = value as? UIFont else {
        return
      }
      let isBold = value.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitBold)
      let font = // Your font logic here based on traits
      str.removeAttribute(.font, range: range)
      str.addAttribute(.font, value: font, range: range)
      str.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: range)
    }
    str.endEditing()
```

I have not gone over performance issues on this yet for larger pdfs, but it does not seem to take up too many resources for pdfs between 10-20 pages. For a higher number of pages, I would most likely create an actual paging mechanism and then adjust for each page on the fly rather than loop the entire pdf file.